# How to find out if class properties are private or public?

Tags: php, phalcon

After creating a class with private, protected, and public variables, how can I find out which are private, protected, and public (from outside the class)?

By the way I want to know because I want to extract only the public model attributes I set in /Phalcon/Mvc/Model.

To clarify: I am not looking for a list of the attributes, but the scope of every attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`get_class_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php) could fit your needs

It returns an array of all properties visible in the current scope. In your case it should return all `public` properties.